# Is it possible to create a pop-up input window for a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to make my code more user friendly with some Pop-up input windows.

I would like to get an `numpy.array` from an input window. I have looked everywhere but can´t find any example. Is it possible?

Example of array:

```
a = np.array ([0,1,2,3])
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: You can use ```eval()```, But taking user input carefully.

Comment: Thank you!
Could any of you give me an example, please?

Comment: Will the user be using `[` to make a list?

Comment: Ideally just in-putting the numbers like: 0,1,2,3
But if it makes it much harder I can make them input the `[ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just want a window to pop up to enter the details, so just try this out:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog, messagebox
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk() #creating a tcl interpreter
root.withdraw() #hiding the window
entry = simpledialog.askstring('Input Popup', 'Enter the numbers separated by commas') #creating a pop up window

try:
    lst = [int(x) for x in entry.split(',')]
    print(np.array(lst)) #print the array of it out.
except (AttributeError,ValueError):
    messagebox.showerror('Invalid input','Enter an proper valid input') #to show error message in a window
finally:
    root.destroy() #destroying the window finally
```

I've explained the code with comments to understand on-the-go, though keep in mind the user has to give input as 1,2,3,4(comma separated format).